# Javascript Object mapping, creating parent child relationship to form a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Struggling with the logic:
Trying my best to explain it. I have an array of objects like:

```js
[
{ categoryPath: "client/client one/client two" description: "test description"},
{ categoryPath: "client/client one" description: "test description"},
{ categoryPath: "research/research one" description: "test description"}
]
```

**EDIT:** the expected output, I did a mistake in the expected output.
The client One category should have two attributes, as in the input Object, we can see that it second object has categoryPath as, client/client one- so the description of this should come under the client one hierarchy.

my need is to convert it into an array of objects like the below:

```js
[{
  categoryName: 'client',
  categoryId: '0',
  subcategories: [
    {
      categoryId: '1',
      categoryName: 'client one',
      subcategories: [{
        categoryId: '2',
        categoryName: 'client two',
        attributes: [
          {
            description: 'test description '
          }],
      }],
      attributes: [{
            description: 'test description '
          },
          {
            description: 'test description '
          }    ]
    },
  ],
  attributes: []
},
{
  categoryName: 'research',
  categoryId: '0',
  subcategories: [
    {
      categoryId: '1',
      categoryName: 'research one',
        attributes: [
          {
            description: 'test description '
          }],
      }],
    },
  ],
  attributes: []
},
```

The code which I have written is keep getting complex, not sure if you'll get it, but here: But if you check my code it is returning the circular array issue, and nesting the parent categories in the object.

```js
let baseObj = {
    name : '',
  parentName:'',
  subCat: [],
  att: [],
  level: 0,
}
let masterObj = {};
let baseId = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   //console.log(arr[i]);
   let splitCat = arr[i].cat.split('/');
   let addAttData = [...splitCat, {att:arr[i].name}];
   if (!masterObj[splitCat[0]]) {
    masterObj[splitCat[0]] = {...baseObj};
    masterObj[splitCat[0]].name = splitCat[0];
   }
   getParentRec(splitCat[0], addAttData, masterObj);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(masterObj,null,2));
Object.keys(masterObj).forEach((item, index) => {
    //client//research level
  console.log('new', item, masterObj[item]);
    for(let i = masterObj[item].level ; i> 0; i--) {
    console.log(i, 'item', masterObj[item].level);
    let obj = getObj(masterObj[item]);
    console.log('obj', obj);
    console.log('whole fir',masterObj[item]);
    obj.forEach((objItem) => {
    let prName = masterObj[item][objItem].parentName;
    console.log('current', masterObj[item][objItem]);
    if (prName !== item) { 
    let newObj = {...masterObj[item][objItem]};
        masterObj[item][prName].subCat.push(newObj);
      console.log('v',prName, masterObj[item][prName]);             delete masterObj[item][objItem];
      console.log('after delete', masterObj[item][objItem]);
    console.log('whole',masterObj[item]);
    } else {
      console.log('masterItem', masterObj[item]);
        masterObj[item].subCat.push(masterObj[item][objItem]);
      console.log(item, 'final',JSON.stringify(masterObj[item], null, 2));
    }  
    
    })
    masterObj[item].level = masterObj[item].level - 1;
  }
})

//console.log(JSON.stringify(masterObj, null, 2));

function getObj (obj) {
console.log(Object.keys(obj), obj.level);
let objFound= Object.keys(obj).filter(filterItem => obj[filterItem].level === obj.level);
console.log('found', obj[objFound]);
return objFound;
}

function getParentRec(parentId, arrObj, masterObj) {
    //console.log('start', masterObj);
    for (let i = 1; i< arrObj.length - 1 ;i++) {
        let obj = {...baseObj};
      //console.log('obj', obj);
       let lastObj = '';
      lastObj = arrObj[i];
      obj.name = lastObj;
      if ( i+1 === arrObj.length - 1) {
        obj.att = [arrObj[arrObj.length - 1]];
      }
      obj.parentName = arrObj[i -1];
      obj.level = i;
      /* console.log('l', lastObj, i);
      console.log('iobj', obj);
      console.log('as ',masterObj[parentId][lastObj]); */
      if (!masterObj[parentId][lastObj]) {
        //console.log('wo', i);
        masterObj[parentId][lastObj] = obj;
        if (i >=  masterObj[parentId].level) {
         masterObj[parentId].level = i;
        }
        //console.log('masterObj', masterObj);
      }
      
  }
  return masterObj;
}
```

Please help with the logic, it is for creating a folder expand like UI in react. So anything which is having a similar parent category will appear in that hierarchy. Else it will form a new hierarchy like research. But in the case of the client is getting inside the parent category client and creating hierarchy like at the sibling level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one with `Array.reduce`

```js
const data = [{ categoryPath: "client/client one/client two", description: "test description"},{ categoryPath: "client/client one", description: "test description"},{ categoryPath: "research/research one", description: "test description"}];

const transforming = data.reduce((acc, {categoryPath, description}) => {
  const leaf = categoryPath.split('/').reduce((parent, categoryName, index) => {
    acc[categoryName] = acc[categoryName] || {
      categoryId: index.toString(),
      categoryName: categoryName,
      subcategories: [],
      attributes: []
    };
    if (!acc[parent].subcategories.find(child => child.categoryName === categoryName)) {
      acc[parent].subcategories.push(acc[categoryName]);
    }
    return categoryName;
  }, '-');
  acc[leaf].attributes.push({description});
  return acc;
}, { '-': { subcategories: [] } });

const result = transforming['-'].subcategories;

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

**Edit**

```js
const data = [{ categoryPath: "client/client one/client two", description: "test description"},{ categoryPath: "client/client one", description: "test description"},{ categoryPath: "research/research one", description: "test description"}];

const transforming = data.reduce((acc, {categoryPath, description}) => {
  categoryPath.split('/').reduce((parent, categoryName, index) => {
    acc[categoryName] = acc[categoryName] || {
      categoryId: index.toString(),
      categoryName: categoryName,
      subcategories: [],
      attributes: []
    };
    if (index > 0) {
      acc[categoryName].attributes.push({description})
    }
    if (!acc[parent].subcategories.find(child => child.categoryName === categoryName)) {
      acc[parent].subcategories.push(acc[categoryName]);
    }
    return categoryName;
  }, '-');
  return acc;
}, { '-': { subcategories: [] } });

const result = transforming['-'].subcategories;

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Thank you @ProGu, this reduce is version is cool, the only thing here is that, at the 
 level "client one" there should be two attributes, as in the Input second object we have, categoryPath =" client/client one" so it means our attributes will have two objects (description ones). Can tweak it a bit to fill up this?

Comment: @Nikhil the `attributes` sections are same as your expected output in the question. There are three `description` values for *client two*, *client one* and *research one* respectively. Not sure about *should be two attributes*, do I miss anything?

Comment: your solution is perfect, It is my mistake, apologies for that. I have updated the expected output, the "client one" should have two attributes, as per the input the second input object contains, gategoryPath as "client/client one" which mean we have to combine the attributes at that level.  We need this correction in code.

Comment: Thank you, @ProGu.  for the great help. You cracked it.

Comment: @Nikhil I guess the tricky part is that `acc` keeps reference to every node, when we encounter `client one` for second time, `acc['client one']` finds the one set previously, so as doing update to the same node.

Comment: Thanks @ProGu, was able test it. The other concern (final), that in the case of categoryPath is null or undefined, but it has a description, it should return the attributes at the root level.

Comment: @Nikhil in my understanding, the root level for the example inputs is either `client` or `research`, an additional entry with `description` only won't be able to find either node.

Comment: You're correct with the initial input, but in case of:

[{ categoryPath: "client/client one/client two" description: "test description"},
{ categoryPath: "" description: "test description"}]
Notice the categoyPath in the second object, in this case, the resultant object should show this attribute at the root level with just this description (out of every root level category but at base level), currently, in your code, this doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: check if `categoryPath` is not available and run `acc['-'].subcategories.push({attributes: [{description}]})` otherwise run existing `categoryPath.split....`, probably this is what you expected